# How to get table.colname dataframe results using SQL Achemy / Pandas?

Tags: sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a join SQL Request where the output of 2 tables is produced :

```
 ss= 'Select t.*, p.* from table1 t, table1 p where t.table2_id=p.table1_id'
 df = pd.read_sql_query(ss, self.db_con)
```

However, some columns have same name since the table is stripped.
(ex: id, id ...)

How to get table.colname in the dataframe ?

Thanks

Comment: IMO it doesn't make much sense to join table with itself using the same `id` column... What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename the conflicting columns with `AS`:

```
SELECT t.id AS t_id, p.id AS p_id, FROM table1 t, table2 p WHERE t.id = p.id
```

Comment: Do I need to explicitely rename it ? (sometimes, I dont know the elements in advance  , using *).

Comment: Basically yes. Similar question with better answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/329931/sql-select-join-is-it-possible-to-prefix-all-columns-as-prefix